# How to expand Toplevel window in tkinter Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I generate new Toplevel window, I want it appears expanded to fullscreen. I have no idea how to do that. It's impossible to use overrideredirect() method in my situation. I have to leave the title of window.
When i set the size of screen resolution:

```
self.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()))
```

window fills all screen space, but it still not fully expanded. In this case I have to press "expand" button in the top right corner of window to completly expand it.
What can I do to generate Toplevel window already expanded?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `wm_attributes` method (of `Tk` or `Toplevel`) to set the `zoomed` attribute.

```
self.wm_attributes("-zoomed", "1")
```

You can find more attributes description in [Tk doc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#m8).

Note that there is also a `fullscreen` attribute, and that you can read the state by passing only attribute name, ie  `wm_attributes("-zoomed")`.

Comment: wm_attributes don't support "-zoomed" parametr (at least on Windows and Python 3.2.3). The solution is self.wm_state(newstate="zoomed") but it's only campatible with Windows OS.

Comment: Looks like you can use wm_attributes("-zoomed", "1") on Linux and wm_state(newstate="zoomed") on Win and Mac. http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.htm#M20

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
root.mainloop()
```